# MVC crud operations with paging and retaining the same page after the record on 2,3..nth page is being updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, crud, paging

**(using another view for editing) [not partial view]. After clicking on save ...the same page should open which consists the record that has beenupdated not the first page.**

**INDEX METHOD IN CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            StudentDBHandle dbhandle = new StudentDBHandle();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(dbhandle.GetStudent().ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,5));
        }
```

**EDIT METHOD IN CONTROLLER**

**// GET: Student/Edit/5**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        StudentDBHandle sdb = new StudentDBHandle();
        return View(sdb.GetStudent().Find(smodel => smodel.UserId == id));
    }

    **// POST: Student/Edit/5**


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, StudentModel smodel)
    {
        try
        {
            StudentDBHandle sdb = new StudentDBHandle();
            sdb.UpdateDetails(smodel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**I have enables paging in index view as :**

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }),
    new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded ,DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true})
```

**I want to pass the page number from edit view to index controller so as to display the same page from which i choose the record to be updated.**

when i used @{ViewBag.CurrentPage = page } in index view it shows error that page does not occur in the current context.

Help to correct where I am wrong

Comment: Not related, but remove the `.ToList()` before `.ToPagedList(...)` - that is killing performance. And your `ModelState.Clear();` is pointless

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Any related solution ?

Comment: use data table for this.

Comment: @KiranJoshi can you please elaborate

Comment: @MansiAgarwal you can use datatable for this. data table provide paging sorting and searching facility on table.

Comment: use https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js and https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css for achieve this functionality

Comment: thank you for the feedback but i have achieved paging. The issue i am facing is different from what you have understood  I guess. I am asking how to redirect to the page from which I selected a record to be edited

Answer (score 0):

You can pass along parameters as anonymous object when calling `RedirectToAction`. You have to POST the current page to the Edit action so you can pass it along.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, StudentModel smodel, int? currentPage){
    try {
        StudentDBHandle sdb = new StudentDBHandle();
        sdb.UpdateDetails(smodel);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController", new { page = currentPage } );
    }
    catch {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: but when I mention it in the index view 
ViewBag.currentPage = page
It shows error

Comment: I don't think `@Html.PagedListPager` uses this value from the ViewBag, no need to set it.

Comment: The solution you proposed is not correct . The previous page is not returned rather it produces url not found error

Comment: "MyController" must be the name of the controller that has the "Index" action. You did not mention the name of this controller in your question. Also, the "Index" action must be a GET action in order for redirect to work.

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

**A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client **
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.